# Is it possible to use Jambi to make fully native feeling GUIs?

Tags: java, qt, cross-platform, desktop-application, qt-jambi

Applications made with Qt in C++ look like native apps on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with Jambi. Is this possible? I don't think there are too many apps written with Jambi, which makes it a bit difficult to get an accurate impression of what my future apps would look like.

I could just use Java without Qt, but apps made that way don't look like native apps either, and that is something I'm trying to avoid.

So, if you have a clear yes/no answer, some examples, or just any suggestions at all, I'd love to hear from you.

Comment: actually there's nothing that makes an app looks like native on OS X because Apple themselves don't really have a native look & feel.  All apps on OS X look different and, worse, from OS X to OS X versions and depending on apps updates, the look & feel of your app can change.  iTunes, which is kinda used, comes to mind.  There are hardly two iTunes version that have the same interface (the positions of the '+', '-' and 'X' in the last iTunes is just laughable).  It is a huge fiasco in my opinion and you shouldn't care too much: OS X users are used to have crazy interface.

Comment: But I like what they're doing to scrollbars in the next OS X version ("Lion", scheduled for summer 2011).  Definitely not "OS X" but shiny.  Thinking of it, Apple is probably the company who's changing their UIs the most often and the amazing thing is that they don't change all apps at once, so it's a big mess :)

Comment: @Webinator: Ha Mac OS X is kind of like that isn't it? I guess I don't really need to worry about it then. That's actually a relief to me, although there probably won't be *too* many mac users using my software. Anyway, thanks for the comment!

Comment: I do have a lot of users using my (Java) software on Macs.  It is a wild wild world :)   And soon anyway Java won't even ship by default on OS X, which will be another major pain for me and many others :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Applications made with Qt in C++ look like native apps on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.

Some people would argue with this, but I essentially agree.

> I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with Jambi. Is this possible?

Yes. Jambi operates by creating a wrapper around the C++ DLLs / shared libraries.  Thus, you **must** distribute OS-specific jars or do some extra work not typically required by Java applications.

> I don't think there are too many apps written with Jambi, which makes it a bit difficult to get an accurate impression of what my future apps would look like.

[Qt Jambi has been discontinued](http://qt.nokia.com/about/news/preview-of-final-qt-jambi-release-available/). Although you have the source available, for most applications I'd recommend using something different at this point. Depending on your needs Qt in C++ or SWT may be better options.

Comment: Actually, SWT looks like a really sensible option. I'll probably end up using that. I wanted to use Qt because of how cross-platform and native it was, but it looks like SWT offers the same benefits. Also, SWT seems to be more "integrated" with Java, since it's written in Java itself (I think). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The QT Jambi has been discountinued by Nokia, but there is a [community](http://qt-jambi.org/development/status-of-the-project/) born to support QtJambi for the next Qt releases.

I think there aren't so many applications written in QtJambi.
I found [Nevernote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/), but the list is short...